# URL の直前に "全角の空白" があるとハイパーリンクが設定されない

Tags: バグ, markdown

本文に URL を記述した際、通常なら自動でハイパーリンクが設定されますが、URL を表す文字列の直前に **全角の空白** があると正しく機能しません。ただし、編集中のプレビュー表示では正しくリンクが機能しています。

**半角の空白あり** (行頭の場合は無視される)
https://ja.stackoverflow.com

**全角の空白あり**
　https://ja.stackoverflow.com