# 参照スタイルのリンクが意図通りに動作しない

Tags: バグ, 却下, markdown

参照スタイルのリンク[Reference style links](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)では`:`の後ろにスペースを入れられます。

このスペースが全角の場合、編集プレビューではリンクに見えますが、実投稿ではリンクが消えてしまうようです。

```
[:http...][1]
[: http...][2]
[:  http...][3]
[:　http...][4]

[1]:https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
[2]: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
[3]:  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
[4]:　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
```

[:http...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
[: http...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
[:  http...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
:　http...

項番3は半角スペース2個で、項番4は全角スペース1個です。
手元のChromeでは項番4のリンクがプレーンテキスト形式で表示されます。

入力間違いに起因し、発生しにくい軽微な不具合(?)と思いますが、文章中にリンクがあっても地の文と見分けがつかなくなる点や、全角と半角の違いをご存知ない方が混乱するかもしれない点が気になったためご報告いたします。

Comment: 関連質問: [URL の直前に "全角の空白" があるとハイパーリンクが設定されない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3395/3060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

開発者と話をしたところ、これはかなり小さな潜在的な問題であるようです。したがって、これが問題を引き起こしていることがわかるまで申し訳ありませんがこちらを却下とします。

Answer (score 4):

直接の解決策等ではありませんが、調べて分かった範囲で書き留めておきます。

---

端的には、全角スペースを使った場合にプレビューでリンクになる動作の方がバグに近い動作な気がします。

[CommonMark への切り替え案内](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3348/3060) でも注意書きをしましたが、Markdown において「通常のテキスト」と「Markdown の装飾」かは、英語の「分かち書き (=空白文字)」を頼りにしています。

例えば「見出し」記法も `#見出し` では機能せず、`# 見出し` のように空白文字を含める必要があります。

「参照スタイルのリンク」についても、payaneco さんは「`:` の後ろにスペースを入れられる」と表現していますが、恐らく厳密には「スペースを入れるべき」だと思われます。

CommonMark の仕様書では [Unicode whitespace](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#unicode-whitespace) の中で、スペース (空白) は Unicode の `U+0020` と定義されています。
全角のスペースは `U+3000` なので、Markdown の中では「通常のテキスト扱い」なのだと思われます。

---

「全角スペースも半角スペースと同じ扱いにする」方向の修正を行おうとすると、恐らく CommonMark の仕様に手を入れる必要が出てくるので StackExchange 内だけでの対応は難しくなりそうです。

Comment: 私個人としては仕様として却下で問題ありません。調査と補足ありがとうございました。